# How setup word_middle case-sensitive search with searchkick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I am trying to setup Searchkick in my Rails application.

I have a model with fields:

- number:string e.g. `NK4321nn1234`

What I need:

- searching for `1nn1` should find `NK4321nn1234`
- searching for `1NN1` should NOT find `NK4321nn1234`

Here is my model:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
    searchkick word_middle: [:number]

  def search_data
    {
      number: number
    }
  end

  def self.sensitive_search query, page
    search( query,
      fields: [{number: :exact}],
      match: :word_middle,
      misspellings: false,
      page: 1,
      per_page: 15
    )
  end

  def self.insensitive_search query, page
    search( query.downcase,
      fields: [:number],
      match: :word_middle,
      misspellings: false,
      page: 1,
      per_page: 15
    )
  end
end
```

Case-sensitive search does not work. As far as I understand, searchkick downcase all `nGrams` during indexing... But why?..

Questions:

- did I write search methods correct?
- why sensitive search not working?

My environment: rails 5.2.0, searchkick 3.1.0

Comment: Can you revise what you have under "What I need", it doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of [this commit](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/commit/860874d73b710968791222c31895052c2dfb2263), you can do:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  searchkick word_middle: [:number], case_sensitive: true
end
```

Be sure to reindex after updating Searchkick options.